# Non-web application with JRuby Warbler

Tags: java, compilation, jar, jruby, warbler

How can I compile a JRuby app using [Warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler) that *isn't* on the web at all? This is always what happens when I try:

```
$ warble
warble aborted!
No executable script found

Tasks: TOP => jar:files
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I must be using this incorrectly. Anyone know how to compile JRuby app correctly?

Comment: Warble is intended to create a "war" file, which stands for Web Archive. It is intended for deploying web apps to a servlet container. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh... Well, I'm using JRuby to create a game with [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) from Ruby, and I want to be able to compile my app to a Jar file. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.rubyinside.com/video-game-ruby-tutorial-5726.html) on how to do so, and at the end it says that you can use warbler. Anything I _can_ use? jrubyc compiles it to a .class file.

Comment: Evidently I'm wrong. I just checked the Warbler docs and it can also create a jar out of a plain Ruby project... something I didn't know!

Comment: Well, I guess you learn something new every day hah!

Comment: Ah, found out how to do this (without warbler): https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/StandaloneJarsAndClasses I'm not going to accept this answer, though, because I still want to know how to use warbler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warbler can create a jar file, even though its main focus is to create a war.

In addition to warbler, take a look at the rawr gem, https://github.com/rawr/rawr
If you are trying to create a standalone app that does not involve a web application server, then rawr may be simpler to use, but the commenters pointed out -- warbler does a better job at packaging dependencies and rawr does not support bundler.

Comment: Looks like a little gem for a simple job. Interesting.

Comment: rawr seems a lot less powerful and robust than warbler (does it automatically package gem dependencies from bundler?).  Really no way to use warbler for this? Darn.

Comment: Rawr is a complete waste of time because it has no support for bundler.

Answer (score 11):

[`warble` documentation](https://github.com/jruby/warbler) implies one of two constraints:

1. either a `bin` directory with the scripts and a `lib` directory with dependencies, **or**
2. a [`.gemspec` file](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20) with the required information to assemble the jar

I mention this because the tutorial you linked follows none of those conditions.

Comment: Hmm, I _do_ have a lib folder (with the Slick and LWJGL stuff inside), and I did see that it says a gemspec helps (I didn't know it was mandatory). I was going to create one but don't know what to put in it. Any help on this?

Comment: @Jwosty: just create a top-level bin/ directory and place a single script inside. Works for me...